# How do you know if your vocal chords are coming together when you are singing?

Tags: voice

How do you know if your vocal chords are coming together when you are singing?

I sometimes feel like my throat is too tight. Should the vocal chords be coming together with good technique or should you be able to feel them tightening?

Comment: If they really did come together no air could flow so you would gag.  It happens, but never on purpose.

Comment: Here is a similar question about avoiding that from happening:    https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/how-to-avoid-the-clogged-throat-feeling-when-singing?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

My voice teacher tells me that your vocal chords never come together or they would interfere with each other and wreck the pitch.  She says if your throat feels too tight you need to make sure you are giving your voice good diaphragm support and let your jaw hang loose.  Do some 'ah' arpeggios in that position, then gradually change over to singing actual song fragments, making sure your diaphragm is involved and consciously keeping your throat muscles relaxed.

I would also recommend finding a good voice teacher for yourself and having him or her listen and walk you through some relaxation exercises.