# What is stopping me from Singing?

Tags: voice, practice

I can sing well (well I think so). It's just the fact that something's a bit off in my voice, as if there's something blocking my singing voice. I've trained on a 6-week course and I've seen a lot of changes in my voice, but I can't explain whats happening. Anyone know?

Comment: Possibly related? https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/how-to-avoid-the-clogged-throat-feeling-when-singing?rq=1

Comment: How could we possibly know without hearing you sing?

Comment: I was taught:  "Nobody really knows if they sing well until they have at least two others who agree.  And your mother doesn't count."

Comment: Welcome to Music SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://music.stackexchange.com/Tour and earn a badge.

Comment: The answer to this question is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hang in there, @Josh. Nobody has ever improved by quitting. Just keep at it.

In the end you may have to relearn some things if your voice changes are permanent, but that will take practice, as I'm sure you know.

May I please share something personal that is similar?  I am dealing with a falsetto that has dropped by one single full note, and it bugs the heck out of me.  I can project well until I get to that note that used to work but then I have to switch to what is essentially a humming voice.  Very frustrating.  I am finding that more practice hasn't changed the projection issue up there, so am trying to figure out how to deal with it. But yet I keep practicing.

So, don't give up is the moral to that story.

It might also be advisable to get a medical opinion.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'm new to this website so I was unsure if anyone was going to reply but you did, I also have an audition coming up soon, wish me luck.

Comment: You got it.  Prayer is always a good idea, too!